# what would happen if Imap replica number is more than cluster members?

Tags: hazelcast

i have a hazelcast cluster with 3 members and a imap with 3 replicas. Will the hazelcast assign the imap's all 3 replicas to the same member if 2 members is down?

Answer (score 3):

There will be at most one copy of a partition (primary or backup) on any node.  If you have a 3 node cluster, any backup-count greater than 2 will be treated as 2, and there will be a primary copy of each partition on one member, and backup copies of that partition on each of the other 2 cluster members.  If a node is lost, no additional backup will be created since there is already a copy of the data on each node.  If two nodes are lost, then all partitions on the remaining node will be treated as primary partitions, and there will be no backup partitions until a node rejoins the cluster.